# return variable in render function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

How to return variable in react component render function,
I try to output the list and I have to print some data in the wrap/container tag attribute during the loop.

```
var WFilterOptionListLevel0 = React.createClass({
  loadOptionLevel0: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.getOption,
      data: {"level":0},
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({optionLevel0: data.option.list});
      }.bind(this),
    });
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {optionLevel0: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadOptionLevel0Mock();
    this.loadOptionLevel0();
  },
  render: function() {
    var optionList = this.state.optionLevel0.map(function(o) {
      return (
        <div className="option-list level-0" data-id={o.id}>
          <div className="title handle-slide-list-container">{o.title}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      {optionList}
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems that you should run `map()` over `this.state.optionLevel0` instead of `this.props.getOption`.

Answer (score 0):

React components should return only a single root node in [`render`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render), but your current implementation is returning an array. You need to wrap your output in a single node like a `<div>`:

```
render: function() {
  var optionList = this.state.optionLevel0.map(function(o) {
    return (
      <div className="option-list level-0" data-id={o.id}>
        <div className="title handle-slide-list-container">{o.title}</div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {optionList}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: *"your current implementation is returning an array"* Actually, either it's a syntax error or if ES6 syntax enabled, it's an object with a property `optionList`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @FelixKling. I didn't try running it.